# Empty value check by Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a string which is the following format.

```
var commandString = 'Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}'
```

I have the following two questions

1. What is the out of `var commandString = 'Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {}'` If value is empty like as Sort_By
2. What is the out of `var commandString = 'Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}'` If a value is empty like as Campaign When the first value is empty then need to remove space for second value like Group.

I am not finding any idea, will you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(?:^|\s)[a-z_]+?:\s*\{\s*\}
```

- `(?:^|\s)` - start of string or space character
- `[a-z_]+?` - Match alphabets and _ one or more time
- `:` - Match `:`
- `\s*\{\s*\}` - Match `{}`

```js
var str = 'Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}'


let removeEmpty = (str) =>{
  return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)[a-z_]+?:\s*\{\s*\}/gi,"").trim()
}

console.log(removeEmpty(str))
console.log(removeEmpty("Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {}"))
console.log(removeEmpty("Campaign: {} Group: {}"))
```

Comment: Clean and Sharp Solution, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

We would design optional groups to cover possible or potential options, for instance, we can start with an expression similar to:

```
(Campaign:(\s+)?{(.+)?})?(\s+)?Group:(\s+)?{(.+)?}(\s+)?Sort_By:(\s+)?{(.+)?}
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/KbaEOC/1/)

```js
const regex = /(Campaign:(\s+)?{(.+)?})?(\s+)?Group:(\s+)?{(.+)?}(\s+)?Sort_By:(\s+)?{(.+)?}/gm;
const str = `Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}
Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {}
Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}

Campaign: {campaign value}    Group:   {group value}    Sort_By: {sort by value}
Campaign: {campaign value} Group:   {group value}   Sort_By: {}
Group:   {group value} Sort_By:   {sort by value}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

and we can add more optional spaces simply using `?` at the end of those groups that we wish to sometimes have it, and our expression expands to:

```
(Campaign(\s+)?:(\s+)?{(.+)?})?(\s+)?Group(\s+)?:(\s+)?{(.+)?}(\s+)?Sort_By(\s+)?:(\s+)?{(.+)?}
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/KKUaUZ/1/)

```js
const regex = /(Campaign(\s+)?:(\s+)?{(.+)?})?(\s+)?Group(\s+)?:(\s+)?{(.+)?}(\s+)?Sort_By(\s+)?:(\s+)?{(.+)?}/gm;
const str = `Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}
Campaign: {campaign value} Group: {group value} Sort_By: {}
Group: {group value} Sort_By: {sort by value}

Campaign: {campaign value}    Group:   {group value}    Sort_By: {sort by value}
Campaign: {campaign value} Group:   {group value}   Sort_By: {}
Group:   {group value} Sort_By:   {sort by value}

Campaign   :    {campaign value}    Group:   {group value}    Sort_By: {sort by value}
Campaign  : {campaign value} Group:   {group value}   Sort_By    : {}
Group    :   {group value} Sort_By    :   {sort by value}`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]